# How to Set the Origin to geometry following a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry, origin, curve-modifier

- Plane is placed at Point A
- Curve is placed at Point B

Using the Curve modifier, Plane follows the Curve path at Point B, but leaves behind its origin at Point A meaning the only thing at Point A is the origin of the Plane.

[image]

How do set the origin to stick to the Plane while it moves along the Curve path at Point B?

PS: Set Origin to Geometry doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You are using a _Curve_ modifier. As other modifiers, it manipulates the mesh of an object, not the object itself. Which means, only the vertices of the mesh move along the curve while the object and its origin stay in place. Use a _Follow Path_ constraint instead. I've explained how it works in my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278851/follow-path-set-start-point/278869#278869

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you very much.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you very much.